# How to prevent VS 2008 from publishing .svn folders as part of publish process?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, version-control, publishing

When publishing an asp.net web site in Visual Studio 2008, is there a way that I can force it to ignore the .svn folders in my local working copy so that my target folder does not end up with .svn files as part of the output.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio has a problem with ".svn" folders inside web sites. Therefore, you should apply the subversion ASP.NET hack, which uses "_svn" directories instead of ".svn".

When using TortoiseSVN, this is simply an option in the TSVN settings (see the General page). When using the SVN command line client, then you have to set an environment variable (see [this page](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.3_releasenotes.html) for details).

After applying this workaround/hack, the publish website operation will work as expected (the _svn folders are ignored).

**UPDATE:**

The problems mentioned above, existed with Visual Studio 2003 (resp. the front page extensions it used). Newer versions of Visual Studio should not have the problem.

So the key seems to be to simply set the hidden flag on the subversion folders (_svn or .svn). Then the folders are ignored when publishing the website. (I'm using TortoiseSVN, and I guess it automatically sets the hidden flag on the subversion folders).

Comment: Martin, thanks for the reply. Setting to hidden helped with all but the .svn folder inside /bin. It still publishes the .svn folder in there, even though the folder is hidden. Here is a screenshot showing my local working copy /bin and target /bin.

Any ideas on this peculiarity?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea why this happens. I'm also using SVN with web site projects and have never had this problem (one difference is that I'm using "_svn" instead of ".svn"). Are you using "web site" or "web application" projects?

Answer (score 1):

The bin folder shouldn't be part of your source control, simply right click the Bin folder in the solution explorer and 'exclude from project'.

now use windows explorer, find your bin folder and delete the .svn folder(s).

next time you publish (after deleting everything) you won't have the .svn files there, also, each time you build your solution, it won't look like you need to check in changes.

Comment: But what if you have dlls in there that are not generated by your project?  Like Elmah.dll or some other third-party dll?  How would you handle this?

Comment: I would have a folder called 'dependencies' that is part of source control. Then a post build script that copies all the files in there, to your 'output' directory. This way, regardless of doing a debug or release build, you have the dependencies. [to add a post build script, go to the settings/properties pages of the project, under compile I think]

Comment: +1 for getting those extra assemblies from the dependencies folder you can also use add as link to the project and set its property to be copied to output

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on the folder in VS and remove it from the project, or you can make sure any of the files contained in the folder have their Build Action set to None and Copy to Output Directory set to Do not copy

Comment: The .svn folders don't actually show up in solution explorer (see screenshot here http://screencast.com/t/WR1tmU1WyR3)

Comment: This would also be highly impractical for large projects